# If function needing 3 return values

Tags: function, if-statement

I want to create an if function with 3 return values.

I want it to work so A2 = "yes" if B2 & c2 are "yes", "no" if b2 & c2 are "no", and " " if b2 OR c2 are blank.

Much help would be appreciated. Thanks

I have tried a combination of if(or statements to account for both b2 and c2 but can only succeed in get yes, no, " " if focusing on one of them

Comment: Three return values? This looks like two inputs and one return value.

Answer (score 1):

What you've posted looks like two inputs and one return value, not three inputs. So, in pseudo-code:

```
function getA2(B2, C2) {
    if (B2 == C2) {        // Covers B2 and C2 equal to yes,yes; no,no; blank,blank
       return B2;
    }
    if ((B2 == "") OR (C2 == "")) {    // Covers either B2 or C2 blank
       return "";
    }
    return <some undefined value> // You haven't defined what B2, C2 = yes,no or no,yes should do.
}
```